# My React app gets slower the longer you're using it

Tags: reactjs, performance, redux, react-redux

I've been getting reports from users lately that my React/Redux/Normalizr app is getting slow after not logging out for a few days, however it always resolves itself after logging out/back in.

How does one diagnose what's going on here? Does a larger Redux store result in worse performance? I hear 'memory leak' thrown around a bit, but it doesn't seem like it could cumulatively bring things to a standstill.

I've optimised as much as possible with shouldComponentUpdate and the like, but wasted render cycles surely isn't relevant if it's related to how long you've been logged in.

Apologies it's a little vague, I don't really know where to begin diagnosis, and my Googling hasn't yielded any insights.

Comment: we will need to look at your website or your source code.

Answer (score 2):

Eugh, sorry everyone, this one's kind of on me. An issue with Normalizr meant some entities weren't merging correctly and thus growing exponentially every time they were updated.

If it helps anyone, check your state, and if you find inexplicably huge entity relationships (my user's `notifications` was ~70,000), chances are you don't have a schema definition so Normalizr is just concatenating every time the parent is updated.